# SKStoreReviewController requestReview() if user rated the app will system never prompt him for rate us?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit, review, skstorereviewcontroller

Hi if user has rated the app within the first attempt, then will the user never see the rate us pop-up again ? or he will be able to see after 365 days ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

On each update user can get the popup depending upon where you call "request​Review()"

Try to call this func when your user is engaged in your app.